# How to show subtask under task using parent id?

Tags: arrays, vue.js

In this user needs to show subtask and subdefect under there respective parent task and story according to the parent issue key.
Below is the data format.

```
data: [{
  id: 1,
  issueKey: '3661',
  issueType: 'Task',
  parent_issueKey: null,
  summary: test issue
  },
  {
   id: 3,
   issueKey: '3245',
   issueType: 'Sub-task',
   parent_issueKey: '3661'
   summary: test1 issue
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    issueKey: '2341',
    issueType: 'Sub-task',
    parent_issueKey: '3661',
    summary: test2 issue
  },
  {
   id: 5,
   issueKey: '5342',
   issueType: 'Story',
   parent_issueKey: null,
   summary: test3 issue
  },
  {
   id: 4,
   issueKey: '4365'
   issueType: 'Sub-defect',
   parent_issueKey: '5342',
   summary: test4 issue
  }
 ]
```

This is how it should look in ui

[ui design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PvMSU.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this requirement by making the parent/child relationship in the template itself.

Live Demo **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    content: [{
      id: 1,
      issueKey: '3661',
      issueType: 'Task',
      parent_issueKey: null,
      summary: 'test issue'
    }, {
      id: 3,
      issueKey: '3245',
      issueType: 'Sub-task',
      parent_issueKey: '3661',
      summary: 'test1 issue'
    }, {
      id: 2,
      issueKey: '2341',
      issueType: 'Sub-task',
      parent_issueKey: '3661',
      summary: 'test2 issue'
    }, {
      id: 5,
      issueKey: '5342',
      issueType: 'Story',
      parent_issueKey: null,
      summary: 'test3 issue'
    }, {
      id: 4,
      issueKey: '4365',
      issueType: 'Sub-defect',
      parent_issueKey: '5342',
      summary: 'test4 issue'
    }]
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <ul v-for="item in content" :key="item.id">
    <li v-if="!item.parent_issueKey">{{ `${item.issueKey} ${item.summary}` }}</li>
    <ul v-for="child in content.filter(c => c.parent_issueKey === item.issueKey)" :key="child.id">
      <li>{{ `${child.issueKey} ${child.summary}` }}</li>
    </ul>
  </ul>
</div>
```